# Why do you need a pause function and when do you use it in contract?

Tags: contract-development

It's my first time writing a contract and I am playing with it, working on creating a minting NFT contract. I did a research and understood that the pause function is to pause the contract, pausing all the tokens that belong to the contract. So why do you really need this pause function and when do you use it? I already implemented a logic that sets presale duration and end time, etc. Is pause used to pause the contract to save the gas fees between presale and public sale for my case? If so, would it completely stop the transfer and even prevent the nft being transferred from one wallet to another?

Answer (score 0):

when we apply pause functionality on some function in our smart contract , it will restrict their ( function's) visibility for a while or can temporarily remove a function's ability to work without impacting other smart contract's functions and without opting to destroy the entire contract and start from scratch.
ex.
Imagine your smart contract offers minting an NFT or sell goods then apply pausing functionality on these sales or minting can be profitable for you.